# Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URl showing error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Following code trying to upload json data into MySQL database but showing error like "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL." Not uploaded json data into MySQL dabase. Please help me what exact problem in my code. I'm new user using flask. After run code I got above error.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
    from flask_cors import CORS
    from random import randint
    try:
        import pymysql
        pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import MySQLdb
    import json
    a= [{"JD_Name": "Data Engineer","ID":10,"No_of_Position":5,"Skill_Sets":"Big Data, Python, Hadoop, MapReduce", "Created_Date":"2018-06-30","Received_profile":25,"Interview_completed":4,"Yet_to_schedule":10, 
    "Attachments":"https://s1.amazon.com/jd-upload/DataJD.docx"}]

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config["DEBUG"] = True

    # do validation and checks before insert
    def validate_string(val):
        if val != None:
            if type(val) is int:
                #for x in val:
                #   print(x)
                return str(val).encode('utf-8')
            else:
                return val

  @app.route("/uploaddata", methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "Mysql1!","test")
    cur = db.cursor()
    for i, item in enumerate(a):
        JD_Name= validate_string(item.get("JD_Name", None))
        ID= validate_string(item.get("ID", None))
        No_of_Position= validate_string(item.get("No_of_Position", None))
        Skill_Sets= validate_string(item.get("Skill_Sets", None))
        Created_Date= validate_string(item.get("Created_Date", None))
        Received_profile= validate_string(item.get("Received_profile", None))
        Interview_completed= validate_string(item.get("Interview_completed", None))
        Yet_to_schedule= validate_string(item.get("Yet_to_schedule", None))
        Attachments= validate_string(item.get("Attachments", None))

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO addjd1 (JD_Name, ID, No_of_Position, Skill_Sets, Created_Date, Received_profile, Interview_completed, Yet_to_schedule, Attachments) VALUES (%s,  %s,  %s,  %s,  %s,  %s,  %s,  %s,  %s)", (JD_Name, ID, No_of_Position, Skill_Sets, Created_Date, Received_profile, Interview_completed, Yet_to_schedule, Attachments))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    return 'file uploaded successfully'

app.run()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with mysql, but with your Flask route. How did you call it? Did you actually make a POST request?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you try to browse `/uploaddata` it performs a `GET` request which is not listed in `methods` list. A `POST` request can be perform by adding `/uploaddata` in a form action's attribute.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Arsho for looking this query. I solved this problem used a GET request.